# accordion with floating content - height problem

Tags: jquery, css

I have an accordion setup with owl carousel and floating elements. 
It seems that the height and the floating only works after the content gets collapsed.

No matter which way I try to get it done for the child-elements (grid, flex, table, inline-block) - the accordion behave the same way.

As soon as the accordion was opened, everything works as expected.
What is the problem here?

Ive set up an fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tkvmhnu8/

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3 class="title"data-href="#this">Floating Content</h3>
<div class="content" id="this">
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image v2"></div>
  <div class="image v3"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image v2"></div>
  <div class="image v3"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image v2"></div>
  <div class="image v3"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.accordion {
margin: 5px 0;
overflow:hidden;
background:teal;
padding:20px;
}

.accordion.active {
display: block
}

.accordion .title {
display: block;
position: relative;
font-size: 2rem;
line-height: 130%;
color: #FFF
}

.accordion.active .title{
overflow: show;
white-space: normal
}

.accordion.active {
opacity: 1 !important;
}

.disabled {
display:none
}

.accordion .title {
margin: 0;
cursor: pointer
}

.accordion .content {
color: #000;
overflow:hidden;
display: none;
padding:20px 0 0 0
}

.owl-item {
float: left
}

.gallery .image {
display:block;
width:400px;
height:300px;
background:rgba(225,255,255,0.8)
}

.gallery .v2 {
background:rgba(225,255,255,0.6)
}

.gallery .v3 {
background:rgba(225,255,255,0.4)
}
```

JS

```
function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .content').stop().slideUp(450).removeClass('open');
}

$('.accordion .title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('data-href');
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        close_accordion_section();
    } else {
        close_accordion_section();
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).addClass('open').stop().slideDown(450); 
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(".gallery").owlCarousel({
    dots: false,
    nav: false,
  items: 4,
  autoWidth:true
});
```

Comment: Here is a codepen that may help you: https://codepen.io/bootstrapped/pen/XKyjpP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OwlCarousel needs the carousel items to be visible in order to determine its appropriate width.

Because your carousel items are *not* initially visible, the children elements are stacked on top of each other vertically, and so `slideDown()` calculates the height to be something extremely tall.

Once you open it and the carousel items become visible, OwlCarousel applies the correct width. This is why subsequent attempts work just fine.

---

**Solution 1: Keep the content visible when the page loads so that OwlCarousel can determine the width** - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avu7rems/)

Remove `display: none;` from `.accordion .content` and hide it after initializing the carousel instead

```
.accordion .content {
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
/*display: none;   <---- remove this */
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

```
$(".gallery").owlCarousel({        //Initialize carousel
  dots: false,
  nav: false,
  items: 4,
  autoWidth: true
});

$(".accordion .content").hide();   //Hide accordion AFTER initializing carousel
```

---

**Solution 2: Calculate and apply the width yourself** - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rf07mqjy/)

```
var totalWidth = $('.gallery > div')       //Calculate the total width
  .get()
  .reduce((a,i)=> a + $(i).width(), 0);

$(".gallery").owlCarousel({                //Initialize owlCarousel
  dots: false,
  nav: false,
  items: 4,
  autoWidth: true
});

$(".owl-stage").width(totalWidth);         //Apply the width to the stage
```